# Karate report & karate log to have scenario name with test data

Tags: karate

I am having a feature that has 62 different test data and with the help of `scenario outline+examples`, all those tests being executed.

```
Examples:
|elements|
|1|
|2|
|3|
...
|62|
```

After the run, the karate report has only the feature name in the title. Is there a way, we can also append the test data into the title? It is very much needed in reports and in logs as finding a failure is a little tricky as there are many services being run in parallel.

**Current report:**
[image]

**Expected report**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was so easy, just figured it out. Appending the parameter name in the scenario name is all it needs.

```
@debug
    Scenario Outline: Get forecast of a specific element for a location with <elementID>
        And path 'forecasts'
```

[image]

Comment: just so you know, karate 1.X has the option to also use the ${object.some.path} form: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1359369240227106816